# Is there a better way to do pandas groupby with a map function on multiple condition?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm translating an excel formula in pandas `COUNTIFS(pos!$D:$D,$A3,pos!$N:$N,$E3)`. I have two dataframe df1 and df2, and I will need to count values in a column first dataframe df1 and populate dataframe df2 where the values counted in df1 is equal to a value in df2. How do I check for second condition in my solution below?

`df1`:

```
      id      member        seq
 0   48299      Koif          1
 1   48299      Iki           1
 2   48299      Juju          2
 3   48299      PNik          3 
 4   48865      Lok           1 
 5   48865      Mkoj          2
 6   48865      Kino          1
 7   64865      Boni          1
 8   64865      Afriya        2
 9   50774      Amah          2
```

`df2`:

```
    group_id      group_name  seq    count
 0   48299         e_sys       1       
 1   50774         Y3N         2       
 2   64865         nana        1       
 3   48865         juzti       1
```

Using the answer of a related question:

```
df2['count'] = df2['group_id'].map(df1.groupby('id')['id'].count())
```

the count for the `groupby` first condition works, to add the second condition. I've tried a few solutions below:

soln1:

```
df2['count'] = df2['seq'].map(df1.groupby(['seq'])['id'].count())
```

soln2:

```
df2['count'] = df2['seq'].map(df1[df1['seq']==df2['seq']].groupby(['seq'])['id'].count())
```

But i dont seems to get correct counts for `df2`

Expected results:

```
   group_id      group_name  seq    count
 0   48299         e_sys       1       2
 1   50774         Y3N         2       1
 2   64865         nana        1       1
 3   48865         juzti       1       2
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can `merge`, `groupby` and then `map`:

```
merge = pd.merge(df2,df1, left_on=['group_id', 'seq'], right_on=['id','seq']).groupby('id')['id'].count()
df2['count'] = df2['group_id'].map(merge)


  group_id  group_name  seq count
0   48299   e_sys        1  2
1   50774    Y3N         2  1
2   64865   nana         1  1
3   48865   juzti        1  2
```